# How to Customize ServerRSocketFactory with Leases

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, rsocket

I have written a simple RSocket server and client using Spring 5.2, Spring Boot 2.2.0M6 and Spring Cloud Hoxton.M2.

I am trying to customize the RSocket server's ServerRSocketFactory by adding the handling of leases according to the official [RSocket sample](https://github.com/rsocket/rsocket-java/tree/master/rsocket-examples/src/main/java/io/rsocket/examples/transport/tcp/lease).

I am using `ServerRSocketFactoryCustomizer` to add lease handling.
But when I declare the customizer bean and start the server, I receive exceptions from Spring-Cloud-Stream's `FunctionConfiguration` (version 3.0.0.M3) saying "**Found more then one function in BeanFactory**".

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'standAloneSupplierFlow' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/stream/function/FunctionConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlow]: Factory method 'standAloneSupplierFlow' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Found more then one function in BeanFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:645) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RC2.jar:5.2.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:625) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RC2.jar:5.2.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1339) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RC2.jar:5.2.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1178) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RC2.jar:5.2.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RC2.jar:5.2.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RC2.jar:5.2.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RC2.jar:5.2.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RC2.jar:5.2.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RC2.jar:5.2.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RC2.jar:5.2.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:878) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RC2.jar:5.2.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877) ~[spring-context-5.2.0.RC2.jar:5.2.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.2.0.RC2.jar:5.2.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:66) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.M6.jar:2.2.0.M6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.M6.jar:2.2.0.M6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.M6.jar:2.2.0.M6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.M6.jar:2.2.0.M6]
    at com.equalities.cloud.rsocket.server.RsocketServerApplication.main(RsocketServerApplication.java:19) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlow]: Factory method 'standAloneSupplierFlow' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Found more then one function in BeanFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RC2.jar:5.2.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:640) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RC2.jar:5.2.0.RC2]
    ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Found more then one function in BeanFactory
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:118) ~[spring-core-5.2.0.RC2.jar:5.2.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.cloud.function.context.catalog.BeanFactoryAwareFunctionRegistry.discoverDefaultDefinitionIfNecessary(BeanFactoryAwareFunctionRegistry.java:194) ~[spring-cloud-function-context-3.0.0.M2.jar:3.0.0.M2]
    at org.springframework.cloud.function.context.catalog.BeanFactoryAwareFunctionRegistry.compose(BeanFactoryAwareFunctionRegistry.java:212) ~[spring-cloud-function-context-3.0.0.M2.jar:3.0.0.M2]
    at org.springframework.cloud.function.context.catalog.BeanFactoryAwareFunctionRegistry.lookup(BeanFactoryAwareFunctionRegistry.java:104) ~[spring-cloud-function-context-3.0.0.M2.jar:3.0.0.M2]
    at org.springframework.cloud.function.context.FunctionCatalog.lookup(FunctionCatalog.java:72) ~[spring-cloud-function-context-3.0.0.M2.jar:3.0.0.M2]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.FunctionConfiguration.standAloneSupplierFlow(FunctionConfiguration.java:90) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.0.0.M3.jar:3.0.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.FunctionConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f29b466d.CGLIB$standAloneSupplierFlow$1(<generated>) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.0.0.M3.jar:3.0.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.FunctionConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f29b466d$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$d3c910a8.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.0.0.M3.jar:3.0.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.2.0.RC2.jar:5.2.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363) ~[spring-context-5.2.0.RC2.jar:5.2.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.FunctionConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f29b466d.standAloneSupplierFlow(<generated>) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.0.0.M3.jar:3.0.0.M3]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RC2.jar:5.2.0.RC2]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
```

I am using the following code to declare the customizer:

```java
@Bean
public ServerRSocketFactoryCustomizer leaseCustomizer() {
  // Here, we return a ServerRSocketFactoryCustomizer bean to influence 
  // how the RSocket server is configured.
  //
  // A ServerRSocketFactory is defined by rsocket-java as an API that 
  // is used to create a server-side RSocket, using RSocketFactory.receive(). 
  // Among other things, it is used to configure leases to clients as shown in this sample:
  // https://github.com/rsocket/rsocket-java/blob/master/rsocket-examples/src/main/java/io/rsocket/examples/transport/tcp/lease/LeaseExample.java
  // 
  // On the client side, a similar class, ClientRSocketFactory, exists.
  // This can be customized using the RSocketRequester.Builder's .rsocketFactory() method.
  // See: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#rsocket-requester-client-advanced

  // See: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.rsocket.RSocketServerAutoConfiguration
  return new LeaseCustomizer();
}
```

where `LeaseCustomizer` looks as follows:

```java
public class LeaseCustomizer implements ServerRSocketFactoryCustomizer {

  @Override
  public ServerRSocketFactory apply(ServerRSocketFactory factory) {
    factory.lease(() -> Leases.<NoopStats>create()
                              .sender(new LeaseSender("Server", 7_000, 5))
                              .receiver(new LeaseReceiver("Server")));

    return factory;
  }

  private static class NoopStats implements LeaseStats {
    @Override
    public void onEvent(EventType eventType) {}
  }

  @Slf4j
  private static class LeaseSender implements Function<Optional<NoopStats>, Flux<Lease>> {
    private final String tag;
    private final int ttlMillis;
    private final int allowedRequests;

    public LeaseSender(String tag, int ttlMillis, int allowedRequests) {
      this.tag = tag;
      this.ttlMillis = ttlMillis;
      this.allowedRequests = allowedRequests;
    }

    @Override
    public Flux<Lease> apply(Optional<NoopStats> leaseStats) {
      log.info("{} stats are {}", tag, leaseStats.isPresent() ? "present" : "absent");
      return Flux.interval(ofSeconds(1), ofSeconds(10))
                 .onBackpressureLatest()
                 .map( tick -> {
                    log.info("{} responder sends new leases: ttl: {}, requests: {}", tag, ttlMillis, allowedRequests);
                    return Lease.create(ttlMillis, allowedRequests);
                 });
    }
  }

  @Slf4j
  private static class LeaseReceiver implements Consumer<Flux<Lease>> {
    private final String tag;

    public LeaseReceiver(String tag) {
      this.tag = tag;
    }

    @Override
    public void accept(Flux<Lease> receivedLeases) {
      receivedLeases.subscribe(lease -> log.info("{} received leases - ttl: {}, requests: {}", tag, lease.getTimeToLiveMillis(), lease.getAllowedRequests()));
    }
  }
}
```

My `bootstrap.yml` looks as follows:

```
debug: true

server:
  port: ${PORT:3333}

spring:
  application:
    name: rsocket-server

  cloud:
    config:
      discovery:
        enabled: true
        service-id: config-server # should come from environment

  rsocket:
    server:
      port: 9999
      transport: tcp

eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka
```

My `pom.xml` looks as follows:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0.M6</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
  </parent>
  <groupId>com.equalities.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>rsocket-server</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>rsocket-server</name>
  <description>An RSocket server application</description>

  <properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.M2</spring-cloud.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-rsocket</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-bus</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-zipkin</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope> <!-- See: https://projectlombok.org/setup/maven -->
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
      <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-rabbit-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>spring-milestones</id>
      <name>Spring Milestones</name>
      <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>spring-milestones</id>
      <name>Spring Milestones</name>
      <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

As you can see, I am using `Spring-Cloud-Config` (server) in combination with `Spring–Boot-Starter-AMQP` and `Spring–Cloud-Stream-Binder-RabbitMQ`.

I have debugged, where the problem comes from, and it seems to me it is either a problem of the Spring Boot RSocket support or of `Spring-Cloud-Stream`.

The problem is that `ServerRSocketFactoryCustomizer` is a `@FunctionalInterface`, i.e. behaves like a function and is picked up by the `org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.FunctionConfiguration` class, which internally calls `functionCatalog.lookup(functionProperties.getDefinition())` that tries to perform a lookup for **exactly one** function from a registry.
As a result of me declaring the `ServerRSocketFactoryCustomizer` that registry contains **two** functions, and hence the exception is thrown.

Generally, I would expect that I can declare as many `ServerRSocketFactoryCustomizer` beans as I am happy to, and `@Order` them accordingly to influence the way the RSocket server behaves.
Today, this seems not possible, and also the Spring support for RSocket based on 'Annotated Responders' pretty much hides away the RSocket server socket, which is a bit of a shame.

Is there any way one can customize the RSocket server provided by Spring/Spring-Boot to add leases, etc., like I am trying to do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So this is an issue where a feature of spring-cloud-function kind of get's in a way.
We are discussing it and will fix it shortly, but for now here is a quick workaround.
Simply add a property `--spring.cloud.function.definition=blah` where `blah` is something that does not exist and you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Unfortunately, that did not solve the issue.
The problem is not that there is a default function already registered, but that SpringBoot auto-configuration `RSocketServerAutoConfiguration` adds an `rSocketWebSocketRouteProvider` that ends up in the registry as well. So finally, with my lease customizer I have this registry: `[leaseCustomizer, rSocketWebsocketRouteProvider]`. In the TCP case, a `frameDecoderServerFactoryCustomizer` is added and the registry looks similar. 
I think the "exactly one function" limitation is a problem.

Comment: There is no such limitation though, at least not in the latest available versions. Try snapshots (or at least the most recent milestones), maybe?

Comment: @DaveSyer, looked at the latest sources of spring-cloud-function-context and the limitation is still there: See [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-function/blob/a83d2e70eebec71e80b807c4ed14f8545dc1a0d2/spring-cloud-function-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/function/context/catalog/BeanFactoryAwareFunctionRegistry.java#L224) and also Line 230

Comment: That looks like a bug to me. Oleg’s workaround would work though, I think.

Comment: Thanks Dave, but I tried the proposed workaround. It does not solve the issue.

Comment: I think even the workaround might need a change in Spring Cloud Stream that hasn't been pushed to master yet. I talked to Oleg about it and he had it under control, but it's been crazy this week with Spring One. Should settle back down next week.

Comment: No problem, Dave! You guys are doing a great job. Much appreciated!
Btw. here is a sample project you can use to reproduce the issue.
https://github.com/FWinkler79/SpringCloudPlatform/tree/Issue-Spring-Cloud-Function-RSocket

Comment: Actually I can't see how the workaround did not help? We are not registering anything by default, however we are looking for default and that is where the issue is. However with the workaround I mentioned, the lookup should result in null and all should be good. In any event, I just pushed the fix in spring-cloud-function so the snapshots should be available shortly - https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-function/commit/6c3b574213ee6db239072ed118f7d05a63d084b4

Comment: Your fix certainly helped. Since the workaround you mentioned above did not work, and I could not test your fix via the snapshots (at the time I wanted to test it, it was not yet contained in the snapshot) I chose another route, but had to open an issue for it [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/18549). 
Long story short: the original approach I was trying here, now works fine - probably as a combination of your fix and some refactoring mentioned in the issue.
The issue also points to a sample which shows the intended approach in action.